# How can I call in a sync manner C++ methods from JS (QtWebEngine)

Tags: qt, asynchronous, async-await, qtwebengine

Is there a way I can call my C++ methods from JS in a sync (instead of async) manner? (I'm using QtWebChannel).

If there is not, can I at least use async/await without transpiling?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is possible to use sync manners. The doc said "Note that all communication between the HTML client and the QML/C++ server is asynchronous".
-> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtwebchannel-javascript.html